# .net Binary Serialization - Opt In

Tags: .net, serialization, binary

- I am doing Binary Serilization of big nested data structure.
- Whenever [Serilizable] attribute is added to class, **all the members are automatically serialized**.
- I want to specifically select the fields that need to be serialized.
- As of now i am using **[NonSerialized]** Attribute for fields to opt out from serilization.
- **Is there any way i can opt out all fields by default and then select only the fields i need, by using some attribute ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the serialization yourself by implementing [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and writing a serialization constructor.  For more information, read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DataContractSerializer, all the fields will be opted out by default. You will then be able to opt in your desired field using attributes.